# sencha touch - setMasked called from button handler does not render until the handler is finished?

Tags: button, touch, handler, extjs, mask

A bit stuck with this one. If I call setMasked from button handler which is processing for a long time, the mask is rendered when the handler function is finished.

Is there a way to force paint the mask within the handler?

```
Ext.define('ts.view.chartIt', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

initialize: function() {
var card = this;

//  ...

var submit = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {     
    handler: function(button, e) {
    card.setMasked(true);

    // long retrieval operations

    card.setMasked(false);
});

// ...
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function outside the button handler and call it, put the setMasked(true) and setMasked(false) inside the processing function.

Example:

```
myFunction: function(){
    card.setMasked(true);

    // long retrieval operations

    card.setMasked(false);
}
```

and then inside the handler the code will be:

```
var submit = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {     
    handler: function(button, e) {
    this.myFunction;
});
```